# Use loops to read all text files in C

Tags: c

I know that we have so many different ways to implement a function. anyone has ideas to use loop case to read all text files at once?

```
int readTenFiles(char (*names)[MAX_LENGTH_NAME], int (*ranks)[YEAR], int namesCount) {
    int yearIndex = 0;
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen("yob1920.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen("yob1930.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen("yob1940.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen("yob1950.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen("yob1960.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen("yob1970.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen("yob1980.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen("yob1990.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen("yob2000.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
    return readOneFile(fopen("yob2010.txt", "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
}
```

Comment: Put all the filenames in array, and then loop on it.

Comment: would you give me an example of store text files in an array ?

Comment: strongly suggest placing the fopen() call before the call to readOneFile() so the returned value from the fopen can be checked(!=NULL)

Answer (score 2):

Assign filename list in an array, and then loop on this array.

```
char *filenames[] = { 
    "yob1920.txt" ,
    "yob1930.txt" ,
    "yob1940.txt" ,
    "yob1950.txt" ,
    "yob1960.txt" ,
    "yob1970.txt" ,
    "yob1980.txt" ,
    "yob1990.txt" ,
    "yob2000.txt" ,
    "yob2010.txt" ,
};
int i = 0;
for ( i=0; i<sizeof(filenames)/sizeof(*filenames); i++ ) { 
    namesCount = readOneFile(fopen(filenames[i], "r"), names, ranks, yearIndex++, namesCount);
}
```

Comment: Would you explain why sizeof(filenames)/sizeof(*filenames)?

Comment: This is a convenience way to calculate number of items in array. `sizeof(filenames)` is size of the whole array, and `sizeof(*filenames)` is size of each element of the array. Dividing the former with the later will gives you number of element.

Comment: `sizeof(filenames)` is the number of bytes in the array; `sizeof(*filenames)` is the number of bytes in the zeroth entry in the array.  The division gives the number of entries in the array.  It is a common idiom in C.  Beware: if the 'array' is an argument to the function invoking `sizeof()`, the value of `sizeof(array)` is the size of a single pointer, not the size of the array as a whole.